# How to get URL of hyperlink in outlook when open the hyperlink using SetwindowsHookEX with WH_CALLWNDPROCRET OR WH_CALLWNDPROC

Tags: c++

The below is part of the code in the callback of WH_CALLWNDPROCRET OR WH_CALLWNDPROC as per my understanding
about RichEdit control but I never catch the WM_NOTIFY, but EM_GETTEXTEX it is working fine and return the mail subject (caption of RichEdit). the RichEdit class name is RichEdit20WPT.

```
    if (cwprStruct->message == WM_NOTIFY)
    {
        writetofile("WM_NOTIFY RetProc:", f1);
        switch (((LPNMHDR)cwprStruct->lParam)->code)
        {
        case EN_LINK:
            writetofile("EN_LINK:", f1);
            break;
        case NM_CLICK:
            writetofile("NM_CLICK:", f1);
            break;
        case NM_RETURN:
            writetofile("NM_RETURN:", f1);
            break;
        case NM_RCLICK:
            writetofile("NM_RCLICK:", f1);
            break;
        case NM_SETFOCUS:
            writetofile("NM_SETFOCUS:", f1);
            break;
        }
        writetofile(to_string(((LPNMHDR)cwprStruct-lParam)->code), f1);
    }
    if (cwprStruct->message == EM_GETTEXTEX)
    {
        isURL = true;
        writetofile("EM_GETTEXTEX:", f1);
        number = GetClassName(cwprStruct->hwnd, clsName_v, 256);
        writetofile(clsName_v, number, f1);// return RichEdit20WPT

        writetofile("Subject:", f1);
        if (cwprStruct->lParam)
        {
            size_t   i;
            char* subject = (char*)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
            wcstombs_s(&i, subject, (size_t)BUFFER_SIZE, (LPWSTR)cwprStruct->lParam, (size_t)BUFFER_SIZE);
            writetofile(subject, i - 1, f1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*thes RichEdit class name is RichEdit20WPT*" - that is not a standard RichEdit class, it is a custom class that Outlook uses. So what makes you think it even uses `EN_LINK` for its hyperlink handling?

Comment: Sometimes give another class name as RICHEDIT60W. Actually I thought it used EN_LINK as the standard RichEdit. Any suggestion?